# [php]Load image file to open its content and export as .jpg file

Tags: php

How to create a script which will open file stored on server, copy its content and export/download to client as .jpg file. Is this code proper?

```
<?php
$imgfile = fopen(image/location.jpg);
$loadimg = imagecreatefromjpeg($imgfile);

imagejpeg($loadimg);
?>
```

Or maybe should i do this other way? I'm new in operating image files in php so this is why this code may look odd.

> I want to make a script which will allow to create clean copy of image file but not whole file, only image which it contains, no additional data which image files can store. That's why my initial thought was to use GD to open file for editing and copy it into new image.

Comment: Your source file is always image ?

Comment: Do you want to process the image file or just deliver it?

Comment: Always .jpg or .jpeg image. I want to copy contents of an image file and save them as a new file.

Comment: "copy contents of an image file and save them as a new file"  - That would be a job for http://docs.php.net/copy - but in your original question you wrote "export/download to client". That sounds more like http://docs.php.net/readfile - you'd use imagecreatefromjpeg() et al only if you wanted to process (resize, modify, normalize, ...) an image on the server.

Comment: Yes and no, i want to open image file like for editing but without changing anything and next save opened and "edited" content to file on client's device. I just want to perform fake edit to copy a file to client's device. I know it may sound at least odd but that's exactly what i want to do :-)

Comment: Still makes no sense to parse the image file via the gd extension in this case. The client has no way to detect whether the server created, modified or just read an image from its storage.

Comment: Ok then, what do you suggest as an alternative?

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: As i said already: open image file for fake edit and save it to client's device.

Comment: Please elaborate on "fake edit" and "save it to client's device" and please make it so that it tells more about what you want to achieve - not how. You want to "fake edit" the image because ...

Comment: I want to make a script which will allow to create clean copy of image file but not whole file, only image which it contains, no additional data which image files can store. That's why my initial thought was to use GD to open file for editing and copy it into new image.

Answer (score 0):

[imagecreatefromjpeg()](http://docs.php.net/imagecreatefromjpeg) takes a string (the file path) as parameter, not a file pointer.

```
<?php
$srcpath = 'image/location.jpg';
if ( !is_readable($srcpath) ) {
    header('file not found', 404);
    die;
}
else {
    header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
    // for affecting the suggested file name
    // see https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-19.5.1
    $loadimg = imagecreatefromjpeg($imgfile);
    if ( !$loadimg ) {
        header('unable to process resource', 404); // 404 is not the correct error code for this....
        die;
    }
    imagejpeg($loadimg);
}
```